# Bitbucket plugin is not working on Android Studio 0.8.9

Tags: plugins, bitbucket

When I try to share my project on Bitbucket via plugin, Android Studio shows the error "Can't publish part of repository".

The same error occurs with the official plugin version 1.2.1 and with this plugin: https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector_IC-135.1230.zip

Comment: What extra steps do we need to do to share our project manually. Can anyone guide me please.

Comment: Sorry its too late but I think you can have your solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589908/incompatible-bitbucket-plugin-1-2-1-for-android-studio-2-0