# Incompatible Bitbucket plugin 1.2.1 for Android Studio 2.0/2.1/3.0+

Tags: bitbucket, android-studio-3.0, android-studio-2.0, android-studio-2.1, android-studio-3.3

I have updated version of my Android Studio to 2.0 and is facing incompatibility issue of bitbucket plugin 1.2.1 when loading Android Studio.

Android Studio's Event log is saying:
*"Plugin Error

Problems found loading plugins:

Following plugins are incompatible with current IDE build: Bitbucket"*

Can anyone help me regarding?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try use jetbrains bitbucket connector, open this link and download the package:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1L0bEhoCIrV9Jced1fqdYscI34wwuKyvQ

After dowloading you need install this plugin (Don't extract the package).

In Android Studio, follow the menu items path:

File => Settings => Plugins => Install plugin from disk => {choose downloaded package} => Restart Android Studio

Comment: Thank you Alex, for the fix.

Comment: But this plugin aslo won't work....try to checkout project from version control and you will see an issue or that nothing happens

Comment: First time use "git clone ...", then you can use the plugin

Comment: I get error with Android studio 2.1

20:36:11 Plugin Error: Bitbucket threw an uncaught NullPointerException. Disable Plugin
20:36:11 NullPointerException: null

Comment: Don't even have to do `git clone` manually. Just run VCS>Import into..>Share Project